# gulp watch not always watching during task

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch

Gulp works almost great. It watches and runs tasks properly, except if it's in the middle of running a task, it won't always be watching the files related to that same task in order to run the task again when the last task is finished.

```
[08:30:51] Starting 'composer'...
composer task
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
Process exited with code 0
[08:30:53] Finished 'composer' after 1.62 s
```

EDIT: don't mind the short time; this is just a bad example. The task I'm really running runs in 10-15s under which time it's realistic that I could make additional relevant changes and save.

This is triggered when editing the composer.lock file.

After having edited the composer.lock file and the task having begun running, on editing and saving composer.lock again during the time "composer task" is output,

Expected: the task to run again after it finishes

Actual: the task finishes and does not rerun to accomodate for the changes that happened since

I'm using gulp watch on Ubuntu.

Comment: I understand your problem but why would you do that? I mean the edit & save while running part.

Comment: For the sake of a realistic example, say I'm running a task to compile TypeScript into JavaScript. If I write something and save, then the compiler task runs, then while it runs I make some quick relevant changes, then the first task finishes, but the task is not run again: then the state of the compiled JS files will not match that of the source files since the task for compiling didn't run again.

Comment: You're making quick relevant changes in 1.62 s? I hope someone has an answer for this as I am also interested in it but I can't imagine a solution to this as you normally don't change code while compiling.

Comment: Sorry, the example is bad. The task I'm actually using is something that runs for 10-15 seconds. And I think you especially change a lot of code while compiling if the compiling is automatic on file change, because you might be writing and saving without the intent of compiling and the gulp task still compiling for you.

Comment: I think somewhere else this would be a good topic to discuss. Automation vs the old way of triggering the compile ourselves

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that `gulp.watch()` isn't watching when you run a task. Although there is a [`debounceDelay` option](https://github.com/shama/gaze#properties) in `gaze` that prevents identical events from firing within a certain time window it is so short that it's unlikely that you're running into it. You can try setting it to `0` just to be sure, but that might cause more problems than it solves.

The more likely cause is that `orchestrator` simply doesn't run a task [if it is already running](https://github.com/robrich/orchestrator#orchestratorstarttasks-cb):

> Orchestrator will ensure each task and each dependency is run once during an orchestration run even if you specify it to run more than once. [...] If you need it to run a task multiple times, wait for the orchestration to end (start's callback) then call start again.

I can in fact reproduce your problem by simulating a long running task using `setTimeout()`:

```
gulp.task('task', function (done) {
  setTimeout(done, 10000);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('some_file.txt', {debounceDelay:0}, ['task']);
});
```

The only thing I can come up with to solve this is to manually track whether the task is already running and then schedule a rerun once the executing task has finished:

```
function runTask(taskName) {
  var running = false;
  var rerun = false;
  return function() {
    if (running) {
      rerun = true;
    }
    running = true;
    gulp.start(taskName, function() {
      if (rerun) {
        rerun = false;
        gulp.start(taskName);
      } else {
        running = false;
      }
    }); 
  };
}

gulp.task('task', function (done) {
  setTimeout(done, 10000);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('some_file.txt', {debounceDelay:0}, runTask('task'));
});
```

Comment: Your answer its cool and all, but if I save 3 files, and my build takes 15s. I will have to wait 45s to get result? In an ideal world I should be able to cancel the task and run it another time. I have been looking at https://github.com/kingmotley/gulp-debounced-watch   that uses  https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar but no success yet

Comment: It's not an ideal world. You cannot cancel a task and you cannot start the task when it's already running. (And debouncing is not the problem. See my answer.)

Comment: This sucks on so many levels. There must be an alternative! Thanks anyway @Sven

Comment: @CESCO with the solution written here, you only need to wait 30s, because this script only queues 1 rerun at a time

Comment: @SvenSchoenung Please correct your code example. `if (rerun) {` <- there the `rerun` variable isn't guaranteed to be initialized. Please use `var` and initialize it at the beginning next to `running`